# How to run Kivy app using sudo?

Tags: python, permissions, kivy, raspberry-pi2

I am writing an app in Kivy and a part of the app is to turn off the rpi display's back-light after a certain amount of time and to turn the back-light back on when pressing an invisible button. I need to use sudo python when launching the app in order to open the file:

```
/sys/class/backlight/rpi-backlight/bl_power
```

The problem is that by default, I get an error saying "no module named kivy.app" when using 'sudo python'. If I add the line:

```
Defaults    env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"
```

to the /etc/sudoers file it allows me to run the app with 'sudo python', but then none of the buttons on the app function. The app runs, but touch functionality is lost. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a different approach: make `/sys/class/backlight/rpi-backlight/bl_power` writable to the user running the Python script (most likely `pi`). Temporarily, this can be done with

```
sudo chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

(this grants write rights to all users). But this will also be reset at the next restart. The solution for that is to write a [udev rule](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html). They live in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and on my system, `99-com.rules` was a good starting point. Here is what I have in a file called `98-backlight.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R root:video /sys/class/backlight && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/backlight; chown -R root:video /sys/devices/platform/rpi_backlight && chmod -R 770 /sys/devices/platform/rpi_backlight'"
```

This changes the owner group to `video` and grants group write rights. User `pi` is by default member of `video`. Then all you need is a restart (or `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` followed by `sudo udevadm trigger`) to activate the new rule.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I love you!